# Discretization of a PID controller

Tags: control-theory, pid-control

I've been given a plant transfer function to control trough a PID.
The transfer function is:

$G_{\small{p}}(s) = \frac{1}{(1+s)(1+2s)}$

Doing a little work with matlab I got this PID controller transfer function:

$G_{\small{c}}(s) = 3 + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{2s}{1+\frac{s}{60}}$

So $K_{\small{p}} = 3, K_{\small{i}} = 1, K_{\small{d}} = 2$.
Please note that I needed to put an high frequency pole into derivative term to keep it *real*. That pole has been put reasonably away from the bandwidth limit of the plant (cut-off frequency about $2 rad/s$).

Checking the step response on matlab everything seems to work really fine.

[image: blue is Gc, orange Gc without hf pole]

Now I need to discretize such controller function and provide anti-windup functionality, I'm not an expert but since I need an antiwindup I think I need to divide the integral action from the proportional and derivative action.

Using *Tustin* method and a sampling time of $10^{-3}s$ I got these:

```
uP[k] = 3*e[k]
uI[k] = 0.0005*(e[k] + e[k-1]) + uI[k-1]
uD[k] = 116.5*(e[k] - e[k-1]) + 0.9417 * uD[k-1]
```

of course the resulting command will be `u[k] = uP[k] + uI[k] + uD[k]`

The C code become:

```
double control(const double y, const double r)
{
    static double e[2] = { 0, 0 };  // e[0] -> e_k-1, e[1] -> e_k
    static double uD[2] = { 0, 0 }; // uD[0] -> uD_k-1, uD[1] -> uD_k
    static double uI[2] = { 0, 0 }; // uI[0] -> uI_k-1, uI[1] -> uI_k
    double uP, u;
    
    e[1] = r - y;
    
    uP = Kp * e[1];
    uI[1] = Ki * (e[1] + e[0]) + uI[0];
    uD[1] = Kd1 * (e[1] - e[0]) + Kd2 * uD[0];
    
    u = uP + uI[1] + uD[1];

    // Cut-Off
    if(u>MAX_CMD){
       u = MAX_CMD;
    }
    else if(u<MIN_CMD) {
       u = MIN_CMD;
    }
    //
    
    e[0] = e[1];
    uD[0] = uD[1];
    uI[0] = uI[1];
    
    return u;
}
```

I think each step is correct but I don't feel very comfortable with such high derivative terms and low integral. Moreover I cannot figure out an effective antiwindup feature (I always used it on PI controllers never on PID).
Something like that should work?

```
    // Cut-Off
    if(u>MAX_CMD){
       u = MAX_CMD;
       uI[1] = 0; // Antiwindup
    }
    else if(u<MIN_CMD) {
       u = MIN_CMD;
       uI[1] = 0; // Antiwindup
    }
    //
```

Comment: **1** Why did you make `uI[1]=0` (effectively `uI[0]` is also made zero immediately afterwards). Do you have a text book reference for this type of anti wind-up implementation? **2** "*I don't feel very comfortable with such high derivative terms and low integral*" Is that part of the question? It seems to be un related to the anti-wind-up part of the question. **3** why is a condition on `u` checked for anti-wind-up rather than `uI` it self?

Comment: Re: the high D coefficient - I didn't follow your calculation, but yes I would question it. Likely to amplify noise unnecessarily.

Comment: @PeteW I've not been asked to take noise into account.

Comment: also shouldn't there be factors of $1/\Delta t$ and $\Delta t$ multiplying into the derivative and integral terms?

Comment: @PeteW it looks like the OP just asked Matlab, and it coughed up answers where the $1 / \Delta t$ and $\Delta t$ terms were implicit -- if you account for that, then the gains should look a lot more like the time-domain gains.

Comment: "note that I needed to put an high frequency pole into derivative term to keep it real"  Keep what real?  Why?  What method did you use?  What criteria were you designing for?  If it's pertinent, _edit your question_ with this information.

Comment: @TimWescott because the question was to create a PID controller that was real and not ideal... without that extra pole the controller transfer function will result to have more zeros than poles and thus NON causal (I dont't know if this's the correct english term)

Comment: @PeteW as TimWescott argued this's the result of matlab command $c2d(G_c,10^{-3}, "tustin")$. But doing it by hand with lead to the very same result

Comment: @AJN **1** this's the most basic form of antiwindup I know ... since the antiwindup is typically driven by the integral term it suggest to void the integral term when cutoff is applied **2** yes and no... I'have been a little bit surprised by the magnitude of the differences between integral and derivative terms coefficients and I tought that this maybe was given by some error into controller modelling **3** the condition is for the cutoff not for the antiwindup itself.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Re: extra pole in differentiator - it puts a limit on high frequency gain, whereas ideal "s" has infinite HF gain. "Non-causal" would be if you have RHP poles or zeros, that's a little different. And the term "real" often used to contrast vs "complex", i.e. poles or zeros being complex conjugates - which often isn't a problem (depends on angle in complex plane), so much as an algebraic inconvenience

Comment: @PeteW no no no... I just meant **causal** because if you have more zeros than poles (like in an ideal derivator) outputs are not preceded by inputs. The same *infinite* HF gain is something that's not achieavable in practice then to make it *real* (that's nothing to do with real vs complex nunbers) you need to put an extra pole and of course this should be something in HF (or anyway out of the bandwidth of the plant itself)

Comment: If I understand correctly, continuous time d/dt is a borderline case. if we can stipulate no holes in the function (such as a discontinuity), it can be constructed to be either causal (ie if you take the limit coming from the left) or anti-causal (if you take the limit coming from the right). In any case, s-plane design/analysis techniques can usually be applied without problems, and when we to transform into discrete time, as long as the system poles/zeros are "far away" from the sampling time, it will work. But special attention should be paid to pole/zero cancellation. (your example has)

Comment: uhm... let put it in this way: if $y(t)$  is the output of the system and $u(t)$ the plant command this differential equation $y(t)=\frac{du(t)}{dt}$ is not something you can translate into something physical. Viceversa $u(t)=\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$ is something you can phisically implement. Of course both equations are mathematically solvable.

Comment: @PeteW you mean there's a way to discretize something like $y(t)=\frac{du(t)}{dt}$
and having a meanigful result ? I would like to see an example... from my control theory book this's something that cannot be done but maybe there are exceptions...

Comment: @weirdgyn - I agree in the sense that $\frac{du}{dt}$ is obviously unbounded without a frequency limitation. But as a practical matter, system designers can limit the frequency band and accept the requirement of continuous inputs and outputs, and accept a tolerance on the result. In that case, the discrete approximation works fine. To limit the frequency range and smooth out discontinuities, we can sub $s$ with $\frac{s}{1+s/\omega}$ as you originally had. But what I'm saying is, for purposes of analysis, and also discretization, *under favorable conditions* you can ignore that extra pole

Comment: I.e. the most basic discretization simply as "du_dt = (u[n] - [n-1]) / t_samp" would produce a "meaningful result" in terms of a control loop satisfying requirements. For this to happen, you need enough breathing room in frequency terms (about 10x), between the system's (and the control loop's) dynamics, and the sampling rate

Comment: @PeteW you meant $ \frac{du(t)}{dt} = \frac{u_n - u_{n-1}}{T_s} $ ?

Comment: Yes. It's obviously not "really" $du/dt$, but can and often is practical

Comment: I got what you meant but I was meaning a different thing... in legacy control theory given a transfer function the maximum differential order of the inputs must be lower or equal thant the maximum differential order of the outputs... i.e. more poles than zeros... moreover discretization of non causal transfer functions lead to something like $ u_n = e_{n+1} + ... $ that's obviously wrong. Of course as I said I'm not an expert so if there are exceptions to this rule I'm absolutely interested...

Comment: @weirdgyn - See here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58533/is-the-first-derivative-operation-on-a-signal-a-causal-system   ...  derivative, and even the identity function $y(t)=u(t)$ are both causal and anti-causal. In continuous-time, it's not an issue. In my view it only becomes an issue when you do discretize, since something like $\frac{u[n]-u[n-1]}{T_s}$ most closely approximates $du/dt$ at a point in time a half-sample ago, rather than "now". If I do the analysis in continuous time, and my discrete implementation has sufficient sample rate, I can worry about something else.

Comment: If I'm trying to build something like a bandpass filter for accurate data collection, this stuff really matters. For a PID controller, it usually is secondary importance

Answer (score 2):

Re: anti-windup

Almost there. The essential part of the logic that's worked for me:

- If the output is saturated to the maximum, then do not increase the integrator variable (but let it fall if it wants)
- If the output is saturated to the minimum, then do not decrease the integrator variable (but let it rise if it wants)

It can be refined further, but that's 90% of it

Comment: Interesting .. I'll try this!

Answer (score 2):

Your gains look perfectly fine.  The Tustin approximation* works by noting that $$s \simeq \frac 2 T \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \tag 1$$
then substituting the expression in $z$ for $s$ everywhere that it occurs.  So your integrator gain gets multiplied by about $T / 2$, and your derivative gain gets multiplied by about $2 / T$ -- except your derivative gain is modified by the pole at $z = 0.9417$, so that nice tidy multiplication isn't quite so obvious.

As to integrator anti-windup, there is no best way to implement it.  It's a nonlinear solution to a nonlinear problem**.  There are a few popular ways which I suggest you research.  It looks like you're limiting the integrator state to the minimum or maximum actuator drive -- this is the easiest and most basic form of integrator anti-windup.

---

* Not *method*.  It is the Tustin *approximation*.  You are *approximating* a transfer function in $s$ with one in $z$, and it's best to never forget that, especially when your sampling rate gets within a factor of ten of your fastest poles or zeros.

** Even if your plant described by a transfer function and is thus presumed to be linear, the use of integrator anti-windup implies the existence of some limit on the actuator strength -- since, from the point of view of your controller, the actuator is part of the plant, so have to take the nonlinearity into account.

Comment: The sampling time has been selected as $10^{-3}s$ accordingly with the fastest pole (60 rad/s) .

Comment: I know all the discretization theory Tustin, Euler and other substitution methos... but the typical problems I work on always lead to PI controller and never full PID .. this time have been a little bit suprised by the differences between gain factor of the two parts.

Comment: in my control theory books they refer to **Tustin method** (or **bilinear transform**) ... of course Tustin method use the first order *Padè approximant* in the form you reported but they are called *methods* o *transforms*.